# Concatenate column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I want to select two columns (first and last name) from a database, combine them into one, and stick them into a data set to be displayed in a datagrid. I also need to add a space between them for formatting.

My normal SQL statement:

```
SELECT first_name + ' ' + last_name as userName from Table
```

My current VB statement:

```
strSQL = "SELECT first_name + ' ' + last_name as userName from Table"
```

When I attempt to do this, my application throws the following error: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Add a name or single space as the alias name.`

EDIT: For those asking about the database and/or if this is the correct query, if I format my VB query as follows:

```
strSQL = "SELECT first_name + last_name as userName from Table"
```

I get the proper results, but then the column looks like `FirstLast` and is very difficult to read.

I'm guessing there's something small I'm missing on how to do this properly within VB. Can anyone advise?

Things I've tried:

```
strSQL = "Name = TU1.first_name + ' ' + TU1.last_name"
```

This throws the same error. However...

```
strSQL = "Name = TU1.first_name + '' + TU1.last_name"
```

gives me a result of `First'Last`

Comment: are you sure this is the correct query that is throwing the error? it is complaining about "select into"

Comment: Are you sure it's connecting to the correct database?

Comment: Yes to both of your questions.

Comment: And just to be clear, the query runs fine when you connect to the same database and run it via the SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Yes. Please see the edit I tossed into the OP.

Comment: Interesting problem.  Now meets my requirements for an up-vote :)  Thanks for editing your question with the additional details.

Comment: Try: strSQL = "SELECT name = first_name + ' ' + last_name as userName from Table"

Comment: Jeremy, see my edited OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [SPACE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187950%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function to rule out quoting inconsistencies when formatting strings in SQL:

```
strSQL = "SELECT first_name + SPACE(1) + last_name as userName from Table"
```

**That being said, this type of formatting is best left to the presentation, not data layer.**

Comment: That worked perfectly. I knew it had to be something I'd never seen before. Thank you!